# Error: Cannot convert value of type '(_) throws -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Tags: swift

```
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email?", message: "Please input your email:", preferredStyle: .alert)



        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
            if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
                // store your data
                UserDefaults.standard.set(try.text, forKey: "userEmail")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            } else {
                // user did not fill field
            }
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Email"
        }


        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Add some text on this. The title of a question is not meant to be the only text besides the code.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(field.text, forKey: "userEmail")
```

rather than

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(try.text, forKey: "userEmail")
```

---

The error message points it out:

> ... value of type '(_) **throws** -> ()'

Comment: This is the correct answer I think. The `try` makes it look to the compiler like the closure is throwing.

Answer (score -1):

use this ....

```
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
            // store your data
            UserDefaults.standard.set(try.text, forKey: "userEmail")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } else {
            // user did not fill field
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in 
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
    })
```